# How do work 'set' to delete duplicated value in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, set, multiset

As you know, set, one of the Arrays in python, can delete duplicated value.

like this

`thisset = {"apple", "banana", "cherry", "apple"}`

to

`thisset = {"apple", "banana", "cherry"}`

The wondering thing is 'How do set can do this?'

Has set a loop about every each value for finding whether it has duplicated value?

this way looks so inefficient. So I think is's wrong.

I want to know the delete process. Please answer me.

I search it useing my question title, but I could see only about to delete in 'list'.

Comment: Set is a _container_, not an array. An array is a specific data structure.

Comment: The source code will be authoritative and I haven't read it, but this almost certainly happens on insert. There is no need to loop over anything looking for duplicates if duplicates cannot ever exist.

Comment: Sets are using a hashtable.

Comment: Sets are implemented as [hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). Sounds like you are asking how a hash table can check for duplicates on insertion. Just read up on that data structure

Comment: Thank you to everyone! I didn't know set uses hash table!